# Remove border when have a file

Tags: html, angular

I have a function of image inputs. How can I remove the box border when a file is in that box?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="drop">
      <div class="cont">
      </div>
      <div  *ngIf="urls.length > 0">
          <img [src]="urls[0]"><span class="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="delete(urls[0])">X</span>
      </div>
        <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
    </div>

      <div class="U" *ngFor="let url of urls" >
          <img [src]="url" style="width: 100%;"><span class="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="delete(url)"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this :

```
<div class="drop" [style.border-width.px]="urls.length > 0 ? 0: 3">
```

You can read the [Cheat sheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet) from Angular, you will learn a lot of interesting methods.